# Can vector grid shapefile be clipped with satellite image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip, image, vector-grid

I am working in OpenLayers plugin in QGIS. In order to project the satellite image with respect to vector shapefile I have, Andre Joost suggested me to create a vector grid with CRS system of vector shapefile. As suggested I created grid.

Now my problem is this:

Am I able to clip the vector grid shapefile with the satellite image obtained?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to clip the vector or the raster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  Raster -->Extraction-->Clipper and in Clipping Mode: Select masklayer

Answer (score 1):

The openlayers plugin is not handled like a raster layer in QGIS, so that kind of raster clipping won't work.

You can make a screen copy of the openlayers plugin layer with `Save as Image ...`, and load that as a raster layer.